# Touchpad, touch screen and sounds not working on Samsung Chromebook Pro (Caroline) Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, touchpad, 18.04, touchscreen, chromebook

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Samsung Chromebook Pro and the touchpad is not working, touch screen or sound. It is a Skylake Caroline board I believe. The stylus does work on the touch screen but that is all. Ubuntu looks beautiful on the Hidpi screen and I would like to make this my daily driver! Thank you so much for your time!